# Hadoop 2.7: MapReduce task's total time using streaming API

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am running Hadoop 2.7.1 on a local cluster (all nodes running Ubuntu 14.x or above). My mapreduce programs are written in Python and I am using the streaming API to run the task. I want to find out the total time that all the mapred tasks over all the nodes are taking. How to do that? I am not able to find the job files. (Perhaps removed from Hadoop 2.x onwards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the sum of all the *aggregate* time spent in all your tasks, you'll likely want to look at the counters. These can be viewed on the job history server as well clicking on `Counters` on the left after drilling into individual jobs, or alternatively you can do this more programmatically using `mapred job` commands, for example, to print out all the summary statuses of SUCCEEDED jobs:

```
mapred job -list all | grep SUCCEEDED | awk '{ print $1 }' | \
    xargs -n 1 mapred job -status
```

The closest to "aggregate wall time" that counts as consumed time on your cluster would be "time spent in occupied slots", which is `SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS` and `SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES`:

```
mapred job -list all | grep SUCCEEDED | awk '{ print $1 }' | \
    xargs -n 1 -i mapred job -counter {} org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobCounter SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS
mapred job -list all | grep SUCCEEDED | awk '{ print $1 }' | \
    xargs -n 1 -i mapred job -counter {} org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobCounter SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES
```

Answer (score 0):

total time that all the mapred tasks is job elapsed time. You can look it in hadoop web interface (click specified job). http://ip_address:8088/